# Convert annotations to Yaml

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, yaml

How would I convert this 'annotations' code into Yaml?

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
*/
```

The manual doesn't give it in Yaml and I after Googling for hours just can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type: entity
inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
discriminatorColumn:
    name: discr
    type: string
discriminatorMap:
    person: Person
    employee: Employee
```